# Find if tree is acyclic python

Tags: python, python-3.x, detection, cycle

I am working on a program in Python. I am supposed to create classes Person and GenTree, the program should have data input from a file, where people have name (specific for each one), some info and then parents or children assigned (parent => children):

```
Ales;m;c
Alexandr;m;c
Anna;f;h
Dana;f;e
Daniela;f;u
David;m;u
Hana;f;h
Jana;f;u
Jarda;m;c
Jindra;m;u
Jirka;m;u
Jitka;f;h
Juraj;m;u
Karel;m;e
Katka;f;c
Lenka;f;h
Leon;m;h
Leona;f;c
Leos;m;e
Lida;f;e
Ludmila;f;h
Magdalena;f;c
Matej;m;u
Michaela;f;h
Michal;m;e
Patricia;f;h
Petr;m;h
Richard;m;e
Sasa;f;u
Stefan;m;h
Tereza;f;h
Tomas;m;e
Vaclav;m;e
Vojtech;m;c
Zdena;f;e
Zdenek;m;h

Ales        => Zdenek
Tereza      => Zdenek
Alexandr    => Vojtech
Zdena       => Vojtech
David       => Anna
Sasa        => Anna
Jarda       => Daniela
Patricia    => Daniela
Vojtech     => Jindra
Daniela     => Jindra
Zdenek      => Jirka
Anna        => Jirka
Vaclav      => Juraj
Michaela    => Juraj
Ales        => Ludmila
Tereza      => Ludmila
Ludmila     => Magdalena
Juraj       => Magdalena
Juraj       => Tomas
Anna        => Tomas
Zdenek      => Lida
Sasa        => Lida
Lida        => Leona
Zdenek      => Leona
Tomas       => Stefan
Anna        => Stefan
Tomas       => Karel
Leona       => Karel
Tomas       => Leos
Leona       => Leos
Tomas       => Lenka
Leona       => Lenka
Juraj       => Matej
Lenka       => Matej
Juraj       => Leon
Anna        => Leon
Juraj       => Richard
Lenka       => Richard
Richard     => Petr
Ludmila     => Petr
Petr        => Michal
Dana        => Michal
Stefan      => Dana
Anna        => Dana
Michal      => Hana
Lida        => Hana
Michal      => Jana
Lida        => Jana
Petr        => Jitka
Dana        => Jitka
Jirka       => Katka
Dana        => Katka
Jitka       => Ales
```

There are functions:

- `is_parent(parent_name, child_name)` - to find if parent_name is a parent (grand parent, great grand parent or deeper) of child_name, or
- `get_all_parents(child_name)` that should get all parents - parents, grand parents, great grand parents etc... of child_name.

I was given 2 files - 1 acyclic, 1 cyclic (I have managed to do everything fine with acyclic, no problem there, but have problem with the cyclic one).
This one file I embedded is cyclic and I am supposed to write a function is_acyclic(), which should return True if gentree is acyclic else False and I should edit function is_parent(parent_name, child_name) to be able to work even with the acyclic file. This is where the problem is - I have managed to write the function is_acyclic() , which is testing on each person if they are their own parent, but that doesn't seem to work if the function meets the cycle first... Although, I am not able to manage how to make the function is_parent() to skip all the cycles (eg. A has parents (B, C), B has parents (D, E) and D has parents (A, F), it shouldn't look for parents of A again)
Here are the classes and methods:

```
    import copy

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, gender, education, father = False, mother = False):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.education = education
        self.father = father
        self.mother = mother
        self.children = []
    def add_parent(self, inst):
        if inst.gender=="m":
            self.father = inst
        else:
            self.mother = inst
    def add_child(self, inst):
        self.children.append(inst)
    def has_parent(self):
        return True if self.father or self.mother else False
    def get_parents(self):
        if self.has_parent():
            if self.father and self.mother: return [self.father, self.mother]
            if self.father and not self.mother: return [self.father]
            if self.mother and not self.father: return [self.mother]
        else:
            return ()

class GenTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.people = {}
    def load_from_file(self, file_name):
        data = open(file_name, "r")
        people = {}
        reading = "person"
        for line in data:
            line = line.rstrip()
            reading = "fam" if line=="" else reading
            if reading=="person":
                thisInfo = line.split(";")
                thisName = thisInfo[0]
                thisGender = thisInfo[1]
                thisEd = thisInfo[2]
                self.people[thisName] = Person(thisName, thisGender, thisEd)
            else:
                if line == "":
                    continue
                thisInfo = line.split("=>")
                for i in range(len(thisInfo)):
                    thisInfo[i] = thisInfo[i].rstrip()
                    thisInfo[i] = thisInfo[i].strip(" ")
                self.people[thisInfo[1]].add_parent(self.people[thisInfo[0]])
                self.people[thisInfo[0]].add_child(self.people[thisInfo[1]])

    def is_acyclic(self):
        people = self.people
        for i in self.people:
            if self.is_parent(i,i):
                return False
        return True

    def is_parent(self, parent_name, child_name):
        child = self.people[child_name]
        parents = child.get_parents()
        if parent_name in [i.name for i in parents]:
            return True
        else:
            for i in parents:
                if self.is_parent(parent_name, i.name):
                    return True
        return False

    def get_all_parents(self, child_name, ret=()):
        child = self.people[child_name]
        parents = set(child.get_parents())
        if parents:
            for p in parents:
                ret = set(self.get_all_parents(p.name , ret))
        return parents.union(ret)

    def get_all_children_list(self, children):
        for i in children:
            children += self.get_all_children_list(i.children)
        return children

    def get_all_children(self, parent_name):
        parent = self.people[parent_name]
        children = parent.get_children()
        return set(self.get_all_children_list(children))

g = GenTree()
g.load_from_file("data_b")
print(g.is_parent("Sasa", "Richard"))
```

Comment: don't know how to do it in python, but there is a cycle : Ales -> Ludmila -> Petr -> Jitka -> Ales. Plus, there are two subgraphs.

Comment: Yes, I know about the cycle, but I need to find with python if there is a cycle:(

Comment: I ddg that : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/, seems working.

Comment: Traditionally, in a tree, each node only has 1 parent but can have multiple children; what does having multiple parents even mean in this context?